# java keep looping if user input is not an integer

Tags: java

I have tried similar codes in this site but nothing works for me. So I want the program to keep asking the user to input an integer if its not integer. If the credit card is integer then go to expiration date and if it is valid then print invoice. I tried if and while loop, also try and catch but I guess my logic is broken. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type 'quit' to exit payment");
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    String name = s.next();
    s.nextLine();

    if (name.equals("quit"))
    {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Enter address: ");
    String address = s.nextLine();

    if (address.equals("quit"))
    {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Type '000' to exit payment");
    System.out.println("Enter card number: ");
    @override
    int cardNo = s.nextInt();
    if (cardNo == 000) 
    {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Enter card expiration date: (DDMMYY)");
    int expirationDate = s.nextInt();

    if (expirationDate == 000)
    {
        return;
    }

    //if input is ok then printing invoice
}
```

Comment: Posting the `while` loop that you tried would probably be helpful.

Comment: Please paste your whole code and not just part.

Comment: Does this code even compile for you?

Comment: I've posted the relevant code only because the full code is 600 lines long. Not a good oo practice, but thats what I have right now. The whole code compiles. I've removed the main method in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, I'll also note a few things afterwards about quitting your application

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = "", address = "";
int cardNo = 0, expirationDate = 0;

while(name == "" || address == "" || cardNo == 0 || expirationDate == 0)
{ 
    System.out.println("Type 'quit' to exit payment");

    //Get Name
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    name = s.nextLine();
    if (name.equals("quit")){return;}

    //Get address
    System.out.print("Enter address: ");
    address = s.nextLine();
    if (address.equals("quit")){return;}

    System.out.println("Type '-1' to exit payment");

    //Get card number continually until an integer is entered
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter card number: ");
        try {
            cardNo = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
    } while (true);
    if (cardNo == -1) {return;}

    //Get card expiration date continually until an integer is entered
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter card expiration date: (DDMMYY)");
        try {
            expirationDate = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
    } while (true);
    if (expirationDate == -1){return;}
}
```

You might have noticed I changed what to enter when quitting at the card number and expiration date part of the program from `000` to `-1`. This is because `000` converted to an int will have the value of `0`, so the user would never be able to exit your application.

Answer (score 0):

Remember `.nextLine()` gets the next element each time you call the method . so it is better to assign it to the variable before processing .

From [`docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) ,

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.
>       Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the
>   line to skip if no line separators are present.